# Why EXISTS statement works differently in delete and update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

Please tell me what am I missing with EXISTS statement. I'm following this website. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-exists/

I have two tables. Customers and Orders.

[image: (img)]

and here is delete query.

```
DELETE 
FROM Orders
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Customers
              WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.c_id
              AND Customers.lname = '4');
```

At first, I thought this delete query will delete the whole table as EXISTS returns TRUE(I mean, there IS a row with customers.lname = '4') But here is the result:

[image]

subquery returns True?? and the row with `lname = 4` is deleted.
So I expected update query will update the row with `customer_id = 401` like it just did for delete.
But here is the result :

```
UPDATE Customers
SET lname = 'aaa'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Customers
              WHERE customer_id = 401);
```

[image]

Whole table is updated like EXISTS just returns True. This really confuses me. Why EXISTS works differently for delete and update? Or did I do something wrong(I think so, but I can't figure it out myself)? What happened to update query and delete query?

Comment: Notice that your first exists query is more complex than the second. Notably, it contains an *outer reference* which makes it a *correlated* subquery which is (potentially) evaluated for each row.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I just understand what correlated subquery is and how it works! Correlated subquery makes exists check for each row.

Comment: Please do not use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

In the first query you are performing the exists check for each row as you are referring the source table (orders.c_id):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.customer_id = Orders.c_id
AND Customers.lname = '4'
```

while in the second query you are not and you have just a true or false condition acting as if block.

Comment: Thanks! I just understand how this works. So in delete, 'EXISTS' checks join subquery for each row and delete when it's True. in update, 'EXISTS' checks subquery and when it's True, it updates whole table! So the point is, delete query contains JOIN method and it makes the differences. Am I right?

Comment: @solee Yes, you are right.